# Is there a way to update the original x and y position of an object after I move it with a method?

Tags: python, function, class, parameter-passing, coordinates

I'm creating an object Block which I assign an X and Y position among other arguments, I want to be able to move it through a method `move()` by `x` and `y` units and have the original `x` and `y` position updated, so as to when I call say `xyRange()` before moving the object, I get the original `x`, `y` position, and when I do so after `move()`, I get the updated `x`, `y` position.

Below is what I've tried but I think I'm missing some crucial aspect because I get an error that my object 'Block' has no such attribute.

```
    def X(self):
        x = self.xPosition
        return x

    def Y(self):
        y = self.yPosition
        return y

    def xyRange(self):
        xRange = self.X() + self.toBlock.absX()
        yRange = self.Y() + self.toBlock.absY()
        return xRange, yRange

    def move(self, moveX=None, moveY=None):
        absX = self.absX()
        absY = self.absY()
        self.moveX = moveX
        if(self.moveX == None):
            moveX = 0
        self.moveY = moveY
        if(self.moveY == None):
            moveY = 0
        absoluteX = absX + moveX
        absoluteY = absY + moveY
        return absoluteX, absoluteY

    def absX(self):
        absoluteX = self.X() + self.toBlockId.absX()
        return absoluteX

    def absY(self):
        absoluteY = self.Y() + self.toBlockId.absY()
        return absoluteY
```

So I have functions `X()` and `Y()` to take in the parameters from the constructor and be able to manipulate them in other functions, also `absX()` and `absY()` to track the objects actual position in the grid and `xyRange()` function that basically does the same thing but just returns the tuple of `x`, `y` parameter (lets say for convenience sake). But I can't seem to figure out how to update my original X and Y positions.

Say I start with a `block1.xyRange()` that returns `(2, 2)`
then I `block1.move(2, 2)`, which you'd expect when I ran `block1.xyRange()` again, would return `(4, 4)`. But if I try adding the `self.moveX` and `self.moveY` parameters from the move function to the `X()` and `Y()` function, I get an error saying that object 'Block' has no attribute 'moveX' or 'moveY'. I assume that this is because its calling itself. But I can't figure out how to fix it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in your move method, you forgot to set the updated (absoluteX and absoluteY) values to the object fields (self.xPosition and self.yPosition). That is why you never get the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def move(self, moveX=None, moveY=None):
    self.moveX = moveX
    if(self.moveX == None):
        moveX = 0
    self.moveY = moveY
    if(self.moveY == None):
        moveY = 0
    self.absoluteX = self.absX() + moveX
    self.absoluteY = self.absY() + moveY
    return self.absoluteX, self.absoluteY
```